# No containers on Docker Shipyard GUI startup

Tags: docker

I am trying to familiarize myself with Docker Shipyard but I running into several issues.

Firstly, when I log into the Docker Shipyard GUI, I think I am suppose to be greeted by a list of containers already running in the 'Containers' tab of the GUI. From the Docker Shipyard docs, this is suppose to match 'Docker ps'. My GUI shows no containers -- not even the ones needed for Shipyard itself.

Secondly, I can't seem to load any of my existing Docker Images into Containers. The images I want to load with Shipyard already exist and and visible on the command line when I run Docker images.

Where am I going wrong?

The container logs for docker-shipyard controller show:

```
INFO[0000] shipyard version 3.1.0                       
DEBU[0000] setting up rethinkdb session                 
INFO[0000] checking database                            
DEBU[0003] connected to docker: url=tcp://swarm:3375    
DEBU[0003] configured docker proxy target: http://swarm:3375 
INFO[0003] created admin user: username: admin password: shipyard 
INFO[0003] controller listening on :8080                
WARN[1022] unauthorized request for /containers/json from 192.168.205.128:35850 
DEBU[1029] GET: /containers/json?all=1
```

Comment: Check logs in your shipyard docker containers.  specially the shipyard-controller container.

Comment: What does WARN[1022] mean?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the Centos 7 firewall was preventing Shipyard from connecting to Docker. Running the command below solved my issue:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0
```

My containers and images are now populating correctly on the Shipyard GUI.

More info: http://www.tuan.nguoianphu.com/Docker-WEB-UI-by_Shipyard